# JavaBeans place

Tags: jsp, javabeans

Where should I place my JavaBeans?

Is it right that I should place them under WEB-INF/jsp/beans or somewhere else?

I use GlassFish.

Comment: It are just Java classes. Where do you place your Java classes?

Comment: I use Netbeans as my IDE. I have 2 project: a model and a maven webapp. My Javabeans are now in the source folder. So that's ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically JavaBeans are the entities which are

- made for re-usability "write once, run anywhere"
- passing one object instead of multiple
- are serializable, zero argument constructor, accessible through getter & setter

So I think there is no need to think a lot of where do i keep it ?considering you are following coding standard. 
I will suggest `WEB-INF\classes\com\myproject\beans`